# parse comma seperated values in argumentlist that's seperated by commas

Tags: regex, go

So i have this regex:

```
=([0-9A-Za-z_-]+),?
```

and i need have a string like:

```
foo=bar,pine=apple,tree,bar=bie
or
foo=bar,pine=apple,tree
or 
pine=apple,tree
```

the regex works for cases where i only have 1 value.
but since we have comma's in the list of values for the key.
the regex just craps out and my code does half of what i want it to do but doesn't get the 2nd value.

How do i fix my regex to take both values regardless of where in the string it is?
alone, between 2 others, at the end.

i tried some stuff but couldn't figure it out.

Attempt 1:

```
=([0-9A-Za-z,_-]+),=?
```

In this case, it matches the one where it's in the middle but it fails on the others because = does not exist.

Attempt 2:

```
=[0-9A-Za-z_-]+([,]+[0-9A-Za-z_-]*),?
```

Matches too bar,pine and tree,bar for example

EDIT::

This seems to work maybe....

```
=('[0-9A-Za-z,_-]+'),*|=([0-9A-Za-z_-]+),*
```

if i use quotes for multi values..

Comment: Can't you split on a comma and then extract the value?

Comment: This is going to be difficult if commas are used as separators between key/value pairs *and* as separators for multiple values.

Comment: Just to precise: you need to get `['bar','apple,tree', 'bie']`, `['bar','apple,tree']` and `['apple,tree']`?

Comment: so i need to split on key=value even if the value is comma seperated.

Comment: Check https://play.golang.org/p/_bTPcVAsbX2, a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/E1rPyX/1).

Comment: I think this would be for more clear in your code if you didn't use a regex. A possible algorithm: 
1. find the next key--a word with '=' at the end.
2. find the next key.
3. split the values list from the slice between last index of #1 and first index of #2.

Comment: We have a ton of parameters that get parsed. i figured it out with the or statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split on variable names - that will leave only the values:

```
s := regexp.MustCompile("[^,\\s]+=").Split("foo=bar,pine=apple,tree,bar=bie", -1)
fmt.Println(s)
# => [ "bar", "apple,tree", "bie"]
```

[Go Demo](https://play.golang.org/p/XY6an7a-VnK)

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/a7ZrYC/2)